# Timestamp value behind by 4 hours

Tags: python, timestamp

I have the string `"20150219-0700"` to represent a time. I want to get the timestamp of this value in milliseconds. What I did was:

```
extracted_ts = "20150219-0700"

int_ts = int(datetime.datetime.strptime(extracted_ts, "%Y%m%d-%H%M").timestamp()) * 1000
```

However the output is `1424358000000`. It is behind by 4 hours

The correct output should be `1424329200000`

Comment: Welcome to the difference between local and universal time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `timestamp` method adjusts the time from your current time zone to UTC. If that's not what you want, you can convert it manually using the formula from the [`timestamp` documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.3/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.timestamp):

```
int_ts = int((datetime.datetime.strptime(extracted_ts, "%Y%m%d-%H%M") - datetime.datetime(1970,1,1)).total_seconds()) * 1000
```

Comment: it fails if the input is not in UTC and there is not enough info in the question to determine the timezone with certainty. Also, `int(diff.total_seconds())*1000` might lose precision in the general case. See [how both issues are handled in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28779031/4279)

Answer (score 2):

Since you are using python3, how about:

```
from datetime import datetime, timezone
s = "20150219-0700"
d = datetime.strptime(s, "%Y%m%d-%H%M").replace(tzinfo=timezone.utc)
print(int(d.timestamp() * 1000))
```

Output:

```
1424329200000
```

Comment: it fails if the input is not in UTC and there is not enough info in the question to determine the timezone with certainty. Also, `int(d.timestamp()*1000)` might lose precision in the general case. See [how both issues are handled in my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28779031/4279)

Comment: @J.F.Sebastian they were pretty clear on what their expected result was, and already had a method that accounted for time zone.

Comment: @MarkRansom: there are other timezones apart from local and UTC (especially in the application domain where Python is used, [example](http://stackoverflow.com/q/28775650/4279)). Read [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/28779031/4279). What do you think is the expected output for "20150619-0700"? Why?

Answer (score 2):

You get the correct timestamp if you interpret the input time string as time in UTC.

Note: that conclusion is based only on `("20150219-0700", 1424329200000)` pair that is consistent with UTC but it is not enough in general case e.g., you get the exact same result if the input time string is in Europe/London timezone (`GMT+0000`) that has **zero** utc offset now but in the summer it is one hour `'BST+0100'` i.e., your code will be wrong by one hour for `"20150619-0700"` if the input is `'Europe/London'` and not in UTC.

You have to know the input timezone to convert the time into POSIX timestamp:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import pytz # $ pip install pytz

Epoch = datetime(1970, 1, 1, tzinfo=pytz.utc)
tz = pytz.timezone('Europe/London') # input timezone

naive_dt = datetime.strptime("20150219-0700", "%Y%m%d-%H%M")
dt = tz.localize(naive_dt, is_dst=None) # make it aware
timestamp_millis = (dt - Epoch) // timedelta(milliseconds=1)
# -> 1424329200000
```

Note: the latter expression might give more precise result than `int(dt.timestamp()*1000)` or `int(diff.total_seconds()*1000)` formulae. See the discussion in Python issue: [timedelta.total_seconds needlessly inaccurate, especially for negative timedeltas](http://bugs.python.org/issue8644) e.g., *"`n/10**6` and `n/1e6` aren't the same thing"*.

If you are sure that the input timezone is UTC then you could leave the input as naive datetime objects:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
from datetime import datetime

Epoch = datetime(1970, 1, 1)
utc_dt = datetime.strptime("20150219-0700", "%Y%m%d-%H%M")
timestamp_millis = (utc_dt - Epoch) // timedelta(milliseconds=1)
```

Comment: I think it's safe to assume that OP wanted a UTC timestamp

Comment: @JuniorCompressor: it is. There is a difference between "seconds since epoch" (what `time.time()` returns) and "seconds since Epoch" (POSIX time) if `time.time()` uses `"right"` timezones but it is rare. People who say UTC timestamp actually mean POSIX time.

Comment: @JuniorCompressor: Or are you talking about *input*? If it is then as I said there is not enough evidence for *"it's safe to assume"* that input is in UTC as I've shown above the input may be in Europe/London as well.

Comment: As I understood it, the input was in in UTC. But you are right, the OP should have clarified the wanted timezone.